# ¿Hacer aparecer un div cuando hago clic en un button?

Tags: javascript, html, web

estoy intentando que aparezca un loader cuando presiono un button en html

```
<form action="sube.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <br>
    <img id="archivo" src="img/iconos/texto.png" height="200" width="200">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="archivo" accept=".txt" required=""><br><br>
    <button  class="buttons">Cargar archivo .txt</button>
    <br>
</form>
```

Quiero que cuando presione el button aparezca el loader ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?
Este es el div que quiero que aparezca

```
<div class="loader" id="load" ></div>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que quieres es que aparezca un mensaje o imagen de espere mientras se hace el envío del form?

Comment: Concretamente un div
Este div contiene un loader que hace la animación de carga con css

Comment: Lo que se podría hacer es el envió del Form con Ajax, así se evita la recarga de la página, al hacer la petición podemos mostrar el **div** de carga en el **beforesend**, que haz intentado?

Comment: He intentado usar el evento onclic, con js usar get.element.by.id y usar disabled

Comment: Si es para el botón del submit del formulario no tiene sentido, ya que el **form** por defecto te direcciona a la ruta en la que envía los datos **action**, por lo que dicha función de carga del div no la verías, creo que la mejor forma es como te mencione anteriormente.